# Is it possible for Math.random() to return a value greater than 1?

Tags: java, math, random, lang

Is it possible to return a value like 1.125155, which is a double value greater than 1?

My code:

```
Math.random()
```

Comment: `random.nextDouble()` ?

Comment: can it possible it 1.0 something like in math.random?

Comment: You'll need to clarify exactly what you want  What values do you want to return?  Do you want values uniformly distributed over some range, or do you want some other distribution?

Comment: Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0

Comment: What do you want ; More than one values or value greater than 1??

Comment: @santoshgore i read out it give in between 0.0 to  1.0 but i have question it's posible 1 >

Comment: its is clearly mentioned that less than 1.0  .

Comment: You are suffering from an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (and from not knowing where to find the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--)) - state your actual problem and ask us to help you there, rather than asking about a particular solution, that is in your case impossible.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt   thank you .. it's not possible in my case.

Comment: public static double random() {
        return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
    }
private static final class RandomNumberGeneratorHolder {
        static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
    }  using this possible  ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible if you are using java.lang.Math. [(Read Doc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random())

Comment: public static double random() {
        return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
    }
using this possible  ?

Comment: private static final class RandomNumberGeneratorHolder {
        static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
    }

Comment: @valamanoj Maybe you can explain what you are trying to achive?

Comment: above internal implementation of random  method can u tell me It is possbile to  get value grater then 1 ?

Comment: @valamanoj no it is not possible.
You can use the result to get a value between a certain range say 0-2 or 0-100 but you have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
 Random ran = new Random();
 double x = ran.nextDouble() + 1
```

The  `x` is now the random number that has `double` value greater than 1.

Comment: Or `x=2*ran.nextDouble()` which will be larger than `1` in about half the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the decimal place using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) like this...

```
Random ran = new Random();
double result = BigDecimal.valueOf(ran.nextDouble()).movePointRight(1).doubleValue()
```

If you don't have to convert back to `double` the code will be cleaner and you'll have more control over rounding issues if you plan on using the returned value in further calculations *(above I have converted back to double as this is what your OP asked for)*.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() returns a double from [0,1]; Therefore, to get it to return a number great than 0 you would have to do one of a couple of things

Math.random() + 1 returns an number from [0+1, 1+1] or [1,2]

Math.random() * 2 returns a number from [0*2, 1*2] or [0,2]

Answer (score -3):

There is a workaround to it if you want to use two values which possibly should be random and never be same(random function sometimes give same value when executed twice), then put your values to a list and use list.shuffle()
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that was his question.  But it's hard to tell.

Comment: yes its not related with my question. my question simple math.random() it possible to return 1.0 something like this in java 7/8.

Comment: Shuffling a List and getting random values from Math.random() are completely different.

Comment: @valamanoj Everybody thinks "more than 1" means two or more different values, instead of a value greater than 1.  I've edited the title.  I hope I understood what you were trying to ask.

Comment: @ajb yes u change it ..